# iptables: How best to DNAT/SNAT with a dynamic (DHCP) address

Tags: linux, iptables

I am looking into building something like a "VPN satellite device". Basically a **Linux box, that can be used in any typically home network**. It should obtain a DHCP lease, connect to a vpn server, and then forward/DNAT/SNAT certain ports to an address within the vpn. So, basically, it **provides certain services that are hosted within the vpn, as if they were hosted on the satellite device**.

First question: Does this technique have a name already? Is this a well known pattern (or anti-pattern) I can read about somewhere?

Going into the details, there is a specific problem that, as it seems, I need to specify the local IP when setting up DNAT/SNAT. At least, that is the cleanest, I assume.

I come up with some interfaces and IP adresses as an example, the device has:

- eth0 with an address obtained through DHCP. Lets assume its 192.168.1.13. But I need code/rules that is agnostic of that address
- wg0 (the vpn interface) with IP 10.0.0.17. This is an address I know for sure. I can use it in code/rules. On that network, there is a server with IP 10.0.0.1.

Lets assume, the server on 10.0.0.1 has an http service running on port 80. I want to setup my satellite box to provide this service on port 80, to whatever home network it is plugged into.

For this, i could have rules like:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth0 -d 192.168.1.13 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.1
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wg0 -d 10.0.0.1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j SNAT --to 10.0.0.17
```

But, obviously, this **uses the DHCP-obtained address 192.168.1.13 , which I do not know in advance.** Which is basically the heart of my question.

How to solve this in the most clean way? In the end, I want to forward about 3 ports in this way. I basically see 2 options:

**a)** create a script that re-sets iptable rules, which is executed after dhcp client obtained an address

**b)** define such rules in a way that they do not require the locally obtained IP address.

a is feasible, but looks a bit quirky to me. For b, I am not sure if its really possible, and does not generate side effects, like DNAT/SNAT-ing to many packets.

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly, but why do you need a `-d` filter on the `PREROUTING` rule? The fact that you specify the incoming interface should be sufficient. All traffic on that interface is going to be addressed to the DHCP given IP address anyway.

Comment: Also, your `POSTROUTING` rule isn’t going to work. You need to SNAT it to your DHCP address, which isn’t possible of course — so you need to use `-j MASQUERADE`which is probably what you’re looking for.

Comment: I think you do understand correctly :)
It just doesn't feel correct to DNAT everything incoming on an interface. I am not an expert here. Are there packets I would DNAT, which I shoudnt? Thats why I am asking...

Comment: I dont need MASQUERADE, tough, as fas as I know. I have seen this working with DNAT and SNAT, but with known local IP. Also the `POSTROUTING` rule does not contain `192.168.1.` addresses, so it should be fine anyways.

Comment: The outgoing packets on `wg0` will have source `10.0.0.1` and destination ip `10.0.0.17`. If you don’t dnat them, they will never reach the correct destination.

Comment: I agree with @xrisk 's first comment: -d is just not needed. I don't agree with xrisk's other comments: SNAT-ing to the other fixed system's IP is completely fine (it could even be SNAT-ed to something completely different such as 172.17.17.17 or kept as is (like a client's original 192.168.1.42) but then the remote WG peer would have to allow it in WG configuration and have a route to it (through WG) ).